# Visual Studio 2010 Assembly Reference Issue

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, assemblies

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 and C# to build WinForms apps and class libraries.  I have some common libraries that I use for all products, and then some product specific libraries for my apps.  None of my assemblies are GAC'd.  All projects copy their output from their respective bin\Debug folder to a common Repository folder, and all assembly references are pointed to that Repository folder.

For example, Common.DAL.dll, Common.BLL.dll, Product.DAL.dll, Product.BLL, and Product.exe

The references between assemblies are typically something like this:

- Product.exe includes reference to Product.BLL
- Product.BLL includes references to Common.BLL and Product.DAL
- Product.DAL includes reference to Common.DAL
- Common.BLL includes refrence to Common.DAL

When all these are included in the same solution, the build depencies are something like this:

- Common.BLL depends on Common.DAL
- Product.DAL depends on Common.DAL
- Product.BLL depends on Common.BLL and Product.DAL
- Product.exe depends on Product.BLL

Which makes the build order something like this:

1. Common.DAL
2. Common.BLL
3. Product.DAL
4. Product.BLL
5. Product.exe

Frequently, when attempting to run an app, I get the following error:

Could not load file or assembly 'Common.DAL, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=4e5249f2e70e1da8' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I have traced the problem down to the fact that not all of the assemblies built from the solution end up in Product.exe's bin\Debug folder.

If I clean the solution, and then rebuild it, the files appear something like this:

- Common.DAL\bin\Debug contains Common.DAL.dll
- Common.BLL\bin\Debug contains Common.BLL.dll and Common.DAL.dll
- Product.DAL\bin\Debug contains Common.DAL.dll and Product.DAL.dll
- Product.BLL\bin\Debug contains Common.BLL.dll, Common.DAL.dll,
  Product.BLL.dll and Product.DAL.dll
- but Product.exe\bin\Debug contains only Product.exe, Product.BLL and
  Product.DAL.  *It is missing the Common assemblies*.  So when I run
  Product.exe, I get the error listed above.

I have checked the properties of all of my projects and properties.  They are all using .NET Framework 4.  All references to my assemblies have 'Specific Version' property set to false, and 'Copy Local' property set to true.

I can *force* the missing assemblies to be copied to Product.exe\bin\Debug by adding references to the Common assemblies in the Product.exe project, but since Product.exe doesn't *explicitly* use the Common assemblies, this feels more like a kludge than a solution.

I've looked through MSDN and Visual Studio documentation to see if I could find out what influences or affects the copying of referenced assemblies, and I've searched SO for similar issues, but I haven't found anything helpful.

I'm at a loss for where to go or what to do next.

Comment: Why don't you want to use project references? If you use project references everywhere, do you still have this problem?

Comment: We've encountered this in few projects and ended up having references to all assemblies from the top-most assembly (*.exe or the website) with "copylocal=true". This is a workaround and I also wonder what would be the real cause of such behavior.

Comment: @McKay, project references are only good when the projects all exist in the same solution.  Many times all of the projects won't be in the same solution.  The Common.DAL and Common.BLL assemblies typically won't be in the Product.exe solution, and even Product.DAL and Product.BLL projects don't necessarily have to be in the Product.exe solution.

Comment: One thing you can do is include the common projects in both assemblies.

Comment: @McKay, I understand that I _can_ include all projects required in all solutions, and use project references.  That would work during development, but there are other external conditions, such as our build environment, which is designed to have only one project per solution.  This invalidates all project references.

Comment: That doesn't make sense.  You can't use any project references, ever?  I would be eyeing up your build process...

Comment: Our build process uses a common parameterized script to build an assembly.  Given an assembly name and version label, the script will get all assemblies for the version label from version control, get the code for the specified assembly and version label, check out the specifed assembly file by version label, and then build the assembly, using the solution of the same name.  This allows us to build any assembly without having to write specific build scripts for each one, but also requires that we only have one project per _build_ solution.  Development solutions _do_ have multiple projects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your question you say:

> I can force the missing assemblies to be copied to
>   Product.exe\bin\Debug by adding references to the Common assemblies in
>   the Product.exe project, but since Product.exe doesn't explicitly use
>   the Common assemblies, this feels more like a kludge than a solution.

I don't think I concur. It's not perfect, but Visual Studio sometimes requires this even intra-solution. It depends on how you are using the class.

While you may think it is a little kludge, it seems like your other (dare I say "kludgy") requirements (one project per solution) make things seem kludgy

Comment: Well, kludgy or not, I have to go with this answer, because it has the least impact on our development process.  We are not in a position to re-architect our build process and all projects and solutions we are currently developing and maintaining.  Thanks for the feedback. =)

Answer (score 2):

You should only reference bare assemblies when they are relatively stable and *outside* of the Solution.

Inside your Solution, reference them from the Projects tab. This will make VS configure the correct dependencies and build-order between projects.

In your current setup, verify the Project dependencies (Solution|Properties).

Comment: I disagree.  If I do that, then any time I add any project to a solution, I either need to add all of the projects that _that_ project references, or change all of that projects references to new locations.  If I make all my references to assemblies in my Repository folder, I don't need to change them, regardless of which solution they are included in.

Comment: I would go with Henk here. If you have many solutions with many projects all crossed out, what you have is a spaghetti architecture. If you have a lot of projects with referenced projects in many solutions: maybe it is time to consider making some interface dlls and hige the complex implementation bellow completely. Make logical components with interfaces between them.

Comment: @zmilojko, I'm not quite sure I follow.  Are you saying that if I have reference an assembly that in turn references 5 other assemblies, I should always include those 5 other assemblies in my solution?  What about any of the assemblies that any of those assemblies reference?

Comment: Solutions don't physically contain projects.  They reference them.  I think you're stumbling on this assumption.  And yes, if you want the most current version of your assemblies, you will include all projects required to build those assemblies.  Pretty standard stuff.

Comment: @Weltonv3.51 The answer is to create an interface library, dll that define an interface that then your 'server' libraries would reference. Create logical components, it will also be easier to split work/outsource some day. But do not reference dlls from binary files if you are still developing them, you are bound to have versioning issues!

Comment: How does that solve the need to reference common projects and be able to build them in an arbitrary solution?